# parsing ls -R output into a variable in Unix

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am executing a `ls-R /files/`

I got the following output

```
./:    nvision
./nvision:    layout
./nvision/layout:    abcd.txt
```

I am looking to get path in the listing like

```
/nvision
/nvision/layout/
/nvision/layout/abcd.txt
```

and  I should be able to copy the required path to a variable

ps: **I am not searching for nvision
I am trying to get the list of folders and files under `files` folder**

can any one help me with that

Comment: ls -lR i tried, but i didnot get what i wanted

Comment: use `find`, `ls` should essentially never be used in scripts, its output is meant for humans.

Comment: i tried with find, I was not able to get it working in my scripts, @Mat, can you please help me with the command, when ever I try Find command in the console I get the following error "Parameter format not correct"

Comment: so what happens when you have more than 1 file in the folder what would you like to do then ? since on ls -R output you have /folder: file1 file2 file3 and so on

Comment: its fixed, there will be only one folder

Comment: find /path -print  will find the files in the path defined if its current folder you can do find . -print. What is it you are trying to find is the more important question - perhaps you should update the question with what you have tried i.e. with the find and what it is you are actually trying to achieve

Comment: I have sent in a reply as an answer

Comment: @gmhk I've updated my answer. If you need further help please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using `find` [(see reference)](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_find.htm)

It would be as easy as `find .` to get the list of files and folders inside the current directory. Change the *.* to any path to obtain the list of files and directories inside that path:

```
nvision
nvision/abcd.txt
nvision/layout
```

To save it to a variable

```
var=`find .`
```

And to add the initial slash to every line (if required)

```
var=`find . -exec echo /{} \;`
```

Here *var* has no special meaning, it's just the variable name.

To later use the variable you can use `$var` or `${var}`. For example, to print it or save it to file:

```
# Print the variable content
echo $var

# Save the content of var to a file
echo $var > /tmp/file.txt
```

Comment: If you have GNU find available, you can use `-printf` instead of `-exec echo`. This saves starting a process for every file found.

Comment: I got that find.exe was not properly configured and it was picking the windows find.exe and it was failing now find command is wokring perfectly fine

Answer (score 2):

You should really use find for these kind of things. Simply use `find directory`. If you require more specific output formatting you can make use of `find`'s `-printf` option. Find is a really powerful tool that also allows all kinds of filtering. Make sure you check the documentation for more information: [GNU FindUtils](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/).

To store the results in a variable use one of the following statements:

```
result=`find ...`
```

or

```
result=$(find ...)
```

You can also use find to directly execute a command for each match using `find`'s `-exec` option. Again, make sure to check out the documentation. It's really comprehensive.

**Update (Mac / UNIX users – Linux users are not affected)**

BSD `find` requires a path. Use

```
find .
```

instead of just

```
find
```

if you require a listing of all files in your working directory.

Answer (score 1):

well the answer is all over this page you should be using find which lists all files found yo can define

where . is current folder otherwise replace . with path you are wishing to search

```
find .-type d -print
```

which lists directories only or find

or

```
find . -type f -print
```

which will list all files only

if you are looking for both then

```
find . -print
```

and if you only wish to define recursive level try

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -print
```

and here is a script

```
#!/bin/bash
for names in $(find . -type f -print); do
    echo $names
done
```